# Apache Flink - Matching with fields having different values in successive patterns

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-cep, flink-batch

Consider the use case where we need to find the pattern for a attack like 10 failed logons from the same device and same username followed by a success logon from different device but same username. This should happen within 10 mins.

Let us say we have 10 login failed windows events with user A as username and B as devicename and we have a success logon from user A with different device C, we should raise an alert. Please let me know how flink CEP can be used to solve the case.

Comment: The above use case can also be extended to the following scenario - Pattern 1 followed by within 10 mins Pattern 2 followed by within 30 mins Pattern 3. Pattern 1: 10 failed logins from the same username and same device within 10 mins. Pattern 2: 10 failed logins from the same username and distinct devices within 10 mins. Pattern 3: success logins from the same username and any device. Kindly let me know how apache fink can manage this kind of scenarios

Answer (score 1):

This is rather similar to [Apache Flink - Matching Fields with the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69737424/2000823). In this case you might try MATCH_RECOGNIZE with something this:

```sql
PARTITION BY user
...
PATTERN (F{10} S) WITHIN INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
DEFINE
  F.status = 'failure' AND (LAST(F.device, 1) IS NULL OR F.device = LAST(F.device, 1)),
  S AS S.status = 'success' AND S.device <> LAST(F.device, 1)
```

The idea is to check that each new F is for the same device as the previous one, and S is for a different device.

BTW, in practice you might rather specify `F{10,}` so that the pattern matches 10 or more failed attempts in a row, rather than exactly 10.