# Apache Flink - Matching multiple patterns

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-cep, flink-batch

We have a requirement where multiple events will be matched through the given pattern.

*Pattern 1 followed by* **within 10 mins** *Pattern 2 followed by* **within 10 mins** *Pattern 3.*

**Pattern 1: 10 failed logins from the same username and same device within 10 mins.**

**Pattern 2: 10 failed logins from the same username and distinct devices within 10 mins.**

**Pattern 3: success logins from the same username and any device.**

Kindly let me know how apache fink can manage this kind of scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach based on hierarchical, or layered, decomposition. Match the inner patterns, creating a new stream based on these matches, and then apply an outer (uber) pattern to this new, higher-level stream.

Implement a query Q1 that uses match_recognize to match Pattern 1, producing a table like this as its result:

```
Query Username TimeOf10thFailedLogin
----- -------- ---------------------
Q1    david    2021-11-11 22:55:19
Q1    fred     2021-11-11 23:10:16
```

and a query Q2 that produces a table like this for Pattern 2

```
Query Username TimeOf1stFailedLogin
----- -------- --------------------
Q2    david    2021-11-11 22:57:19
Q2    fred     2021-11-11 23:11:16
```

Do something similar with Q3.

Then apply a new uber-pattern to

```sql
select * from Q1 union all select * from Q2 ...
```

or simply join the tables on the appropriate conditions.

For an example of using match_recognize to match the inner patterns, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69749807/2000823.